# How to convert '［'　to '[' use python

Tags: python

I use this :

```
    title=title.replace(u'【',u'[').replace(u'】',u'[')
```

But Error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: You'll need to tell us what it is in `title`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The link posted by Ignacio is great, follow it carefully.*

The big '[' is in CJK charset, people here might not have correct font installed to render it. So I use bold **[** to represent it.

If you don't care directly using encoded string in Python, which is highly non-recommended though, just ".replace('**[**', '[')" using string instead of unicode.

If you want to, actually you should, use unicode to operate text inside Python, you need to make sure all texts that you're using are in unicode by `.decode(string_encoding)`. Also, set your global default encoding to 'utf-8' in [`sitecustomize.py`](http://www.faqs.org/docs/diveintopython/kgp_unicode.html#d0e18775), this would make the system to perform `.decode('utf-8')` for you automatically.

Answer (score 4):

That's because `title` isn't a `unicode` in the first place. [Decode before using it.](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/)

Comment: @jsbueno, perhaps you could explain what's wrong with the answer rather then just saying its wrong?

Comment: @jsbueno: [WRRRRRROOOOOOOOOOOOOOONNNNNNGGGGGGGGGG!!!!!!!!!!!!](http://codepad.org/Wq0PLl7b)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need `title` to be a unicode object, not a str object

eg.

```
title = title.decode("utf-8")  # or whatever encoding title is using
```